# How to attach uib-dropdown menu to a table row?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have an uib-dropdown menu. When the users clicks on a row it should show up below this row.

My current solution (http://plnkr.co/edit/sVdR3CLgi5BFuWl5jxWM) is shown below the table.

How can I change that?

```
  <div ng-controller="DropdownCtrl">
    <!-- Simple dropdown -->
    <table class=".table">
      <tr ng-repeat="it in items" ng-click="toggleDropdown($event)">
        <td>
          {{it}}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <div class="btn-group" uib-dropdown is-open="status.isopen">
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" uib-dropdown-menu role="menu" aria-labelledby="single-button">
        <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Well, put the dropdown inside the table cell, not after the table: http://plnkr.co/edit/sUKkYSgsrTmcfPur6Y7C?p=preview

Comment: That doesn't happen here, neither in Firefox, nor in Chrome. WHat browser are you using?

Comment: It actually works. Didn't see your plnkr and had a bug in my try. Feal free to add your comment as a full answer in order I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add a dropdown to each cell, instead of using a single dropdown after the table.

Here's [a plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/sUKkYSgsrTmcfPur6Y7C?p=preview) showing you an example. The main change is to move the html code of the dropdown inside the `<td>`, and to add an `open` flag to each item in the list, instead of having a global one in the scope:

```
  $scope.items = [
    {
      label: 'The first choice!'
    },
    {
      label: 'And another choice for you.'
    },
    {
      label: 'but wait! A third!'
    }
  ];

  $scope.toggled = function(open) {
    $log.log('Dropdown is now: ', open);
  };

  $scope.toggleDropdown = function(it, $event) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();
    it.isopen = !it.isopen;
  };
```